# Xcode how do I include multiple device when exporting for localization when I tick 'Include screenshots'?

Tags: swift, xcode, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

So I am watching the [WWDC2019 video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/403/) about localization, at 26:00, it is showing at least 2 devices, how can I export for multiple devices?

[this is what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQB2n.png), and it only has the iphone11 pro max.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer after playing around

What I did was I duplicate my UITest in targets [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PS3b.png), then change the device of the target to the one you prefer

Then run the test one time by pressing cmd+u

Then choose the project file on the left and click Editor>Export for localization, then you will see the new device showing up

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFaN7.jpg)